# Как сделать выпадающий список при написании в lineEdit(textEdit) текста?

Tags: pyqt5

Как сделать выпадающий список при написании в lineEdit(textEdit) текста без comboBox?

Можно ли это реализовать?
выпадающий список формируется из исходного массива слов, по буквам написанным в lineedit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: При помощи QCompleter в который передается список слов, при этом QComboBox, должен быть editable. С QLineEdit тоже работает

Comment: @Alexander Chernin спасибо)